# Exception Message: TF270015: 'MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '-532462766'

Tags: msbuild, ldap, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner, sonarqube5.2

I am trying to integrate SonarQube MSBuild runner with TFS 2013 and I am using SonarQube 5.2 version and `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0.2` with all the required plug-ins for LDAP, .NET and C#. I get this error when I run the `TFS Build`:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.WebClientDownloader.Download(String url)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.SonarWebService.GetProperties(String projectKey, ILogger logger)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.PropertiesFetcher.FetchProperties(SonarWebService ws, String sonarProjectKey, ILogger logger)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.FetchArgumentsAndRulesets(ProcessedArgs args, String configDir, ILogger logger, IDictionary`2& serverSettings)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.DoExecute(ProcessedArgs args, ILogger logger)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.Execute(String[] args, ILogger logger)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.Program.Main(String[] args)
Exception Message: TF270015: 'MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '-532462766'. See the build logs for more details. (type UnexpectedExitCodeException)Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Answer (score 2):

Only [technical users](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Technical+Users) are **supported** for authentication from *MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe* or *SonarQube Runner* against SonarQube 5.2 with LDAP plugin 1.5.1(and Windows Authentication mode enabled).

Comment: This appears to be the problem and once I modified MSBuild SonarQube Runner to authenticate with a technical user it worked....thank you